# A question on Deligne's paper Valeur de Fonctions L et periodes d'integrales

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

In section 1.7 of Deligne's paper Valeur de Fonctions L et periodes d'integrales, which has a translation

http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~eghate/Deligne.pdf

there are two subspaces $F^+$ and $F^-$ appearing in the Hodge filtration of the de Rham realisation $H_{DR}(M)$ of a pure motive $M$. However these two subspaces haven't been defined, anyone who could explain the definition?

In this section, the author defines
\begin{equation}
H^+_{DR}(M):=H_{DR}(M)/F^-,~~H^-_{DR}(M):=H_{DR}(M)/F^+
\end{equation} 
and it has said later in this section that the dual of $H^+_{DR}(M)$ (resp. $H^-_{DR}(M)$) is the subspace $F^+$ (resp. $F^-$) of $H_{DR}(M^\vee)$, where $M^\vee$ is the dual motive of $M$. I don't understand this statement, and could anyone explain it to me?

Edit, after some time, I have also asked this question on MO

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296808/a-question-on-delignes-paper-valeurs-de-fonctions-l-et-p%C3%A9riodes-dint%C3%A9grales

Comment: Now asked also on MO: [A question on Deligne's paper “Valeurs de fonctions L et périodes d'intégrales”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/296808). (I have added a link at least in comment, since it is recommended to link the two copies to each other when cross-posting. See meta: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088))

Comment: @MartinSleziak Got it, thank you.